# How to maintain logs in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am writing back-end part using Nodejs Express & using mongodb for database so I need to maintain a log for every operation. Which is the best way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js Logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016474/node-js-logging)

Comment: You can use any logger library like banyan, log4j-node etc...

Comment: You can use Winston logging..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston
You can implement it as

```
 var winston = require('winston'); 
 winston.log('info', 'Hello distributed log files!');
 winston.info('Hello again distributed logs');
```

Hope this will help you